Mean ergodic theorem in $L^p$ for infinite measure spaces
The mean ergodic theorem in $L^p$ can be stated as follows:
Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ be a probability space and let $\theta:\Omega\to \Omega$ be a measure-preserving map, then for all $p\in[1,\infty)$ and $f\in L^p(\mathbb{P})$ there exists a $\overline{f}\in L^p(\mathbb{P})$ such that
$$
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} f\circ \theta^k \to \overline{f}
$$
in $L^p(\mathbb{P})$ and $\mathbb{P}$-a.e..
In the book Operator Theoretic Aspects of Ergodic Theory (Theorems $8.6$ and $11.4$) it is shown that the convergence a.e. and in $L^2$ keep holding when $\mathbb{P}$ is replaced with an arbitrary measure $\mu$ (possibly infinite). I wonder if this is true also for the convergence in $L^p(\mu)$ for $p\neq 2$.
In other words, I want to know if it is true that given an arbitrary measure space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mu)$ and a measure-preserving map $\theta:\Omega\to \Omega$, then for all $p\in[1,\infty)$ and $f\in L^p(\mu)$ there exists a $\overline{f}\in L^p(\mu)$ such that
$$
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} f\circ \theta^k \to \overline{f}
$$
in $L^p(\mu)$ and $\mu$-a.e..
(As mentioned, I already know the answer is positive for the $\mu$-a.e. convergence and for the convergence in $L^p(\mu)$ when $p=2$.)

Unfortunately I do not access to paper by Yosida "Mean ergodic theorem in Banach spcae'. But do you think that this paper can help for your question. If you have a PDF of this paper please send me via email

Let consider $P=\infty,  X=\mathbb{Z}, \mu=$counting  measure and  $\theta$  the  shift operator  and  $f$ be the characteristic  function of  the set prime integers. In this case what is the limit you are talking about? does the  density of  prime number is needed? a prime integer is  an integer whose  absolute value is a prime number

The answer is yes for $p\in (1,\infty)$. The norm convergence is a consequence of the mean ergodic theorem for power-bounded operators on reflexive Banach spaces. The a.e. convergence is true for every positive operator of norm $1$ on $L^p$ for $p \in (1, \infty)$; this is a tbeorem of Akcoglu and Sucheston, I think from the 70s.

@AliTaghavi: OP assumes that $p<\infty$.

@JochenGlueck  Yes  I see. thank you!

@JochenGlueck Thank you! Can you please expand on why the $L^p$-norm convergence is a consequence of the mean ergodic theorem for power-bounded operators on reflexive Banach spaces? Do you have a reference?

@AliTaghavi Thank you, I gave a look at the paper by Yosida you mentioned and it does seem to be relevant. You can download it from here for free (https://projecteuclid.org/journals/proceedings-of-the-imperial-academy/volume-14/issue-8/Mean-ergodic-theorem-in-Banach-spaces/10.3792/pia/1195579607.full)

@No-one: The mean ergodic theorem on reflexive Banach spaces is Theorem 8.22 in the book you linked.

@No-one You are well come! Thank you  for  sharing the  Yosida  paper

When the measure is infinite and the transformation is ergodic then for every $f\in L^1$, almost everywhere, the limit is $0$. This by a simple susequence argument would imply that the $\bar{f}=0$.

@user103342 thanks a lot. This observation, together with the existence of some $(\mu,\theta)$ such that $\mu$ is infinite, $\theta$-invariant and $\theta$-ergodic (e.g. see Example $1.7$ in these notes http://www.crm.sns.it/media/event/432/Bonanno-pisahokkaido2018.pdf), shows that, in general, the $L^1$ convergence does not hold. Indeed, if it did, then for any $f:=1_C$ with $1_C\circ \theta=C$ and $0<\mu(C)<\infty$, one would get that $\overline{f}\geq 0$ is constant, and hence a contradiction from $(0,\infty)\ni \mu(C)=\mu(A_nf)\to \mu(\overline{f})=\mu(\Omega)\overline{f}\in{0,\infty}$.

I sum up what has been discussed in the comments. If any of the people who have taken part to the discussion in the comments (Jochen Glueck, Ali Taghavi and user103342) want to post their own answer, I would be happy to accept it in place of my own.
For $p\in(1,\infty)$, the answer to my question is yes, since for such $p$ $L^p$ is reflexive and hence Yosida's theorem applies. The result is also contained in Theorem 8.22 of the book Operator Theoretic Aspects of Ergodic Theory.
For $p=1$, however, the answer is no, and this can be shown by contradiction, by considering an infinite dynamical system $((\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mu),\theta)$ such that $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite, $\mu(\Omega)=\infty$, $\mu$ is $\theta$-invariant and $\theta$-ergodic (such an infinte dynamical system exists: see e.g. Example $1.7$ here). If the $L^1$ convergence held, then by picking a measurable $C$ with $\mu(C)\in(0,\infty)$ and letting $f=1_C$, one would get a contradiction from $(0,\infty)\ni \mu(C)=\mu(A_nf)\to \mu(\overline{f})=\mu(\Omega)\overline{f}\in\{0,\infty\}$, where in the last equality we have used that $\overline{f}\in L^1$ is $\theta$-invariant and hence constant (non-negative) by ergodicity.
EDIT: See Jochen Glueck's comment for a better (easier) counterexample.

The counterexample in the $L^1$-case seems to be unnecessarily complicated. If you just take $\theta: \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$, $n \mapsto n-1$, then the Koopman operator is the right shift on $\ell^1(\mathbb{Z})$. The orbit of every $f \in \ell^1(\mathbb{Z})$ converges pointwise to $0$, but the Koopman operator is norm preserving on the positive cone of $\ell^1(\mathbb{Z})$ - hence, the Koopman operator is not mean ergodic.

@JochenGlueck thanks, that's indeed a way better counterexample.
